# Regex for grabbing an INT from a SUBSTRING

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
import re
data = []

tcp_dump = "17:18:38.877517 IP 192.168.0.15.43471 > 23.195.155.202.443: Flags [.], ack 1623866279, win 245, options [nop,nop,TS val 43001536 ecr 287517202], length 0"

regex = r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(^length (\d+))'

data_ready = re.findall(regex, tcp_dump)
print(data_ready)
data.append(data_ready)

print(data)
```

this code currently needs to grab 2 IPv4 addresses and the length of a packet and cast them into a 2-d list. so far the first half of my regex does just that with the IPv4 addresses. my problem comes down to grabbing the length. i get the output:

`[('192.168.0.15', '', ''), ('23.195.155.202', '', '')]`

instead of the desired output of:

`['192.168.0.15', '23.195.155.202', '0']`

any ways to fix the regex?

## EDIT

so it turns out, the regex seperated works (just the first half or just the second half), i cant seem to get them to work combined.

Comment: but this `192.168.0.15.43471` is not valid IP address

Comment: it is, 192.168.0.15 is an ipv4, the 43471 is a mac address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. You just need to make some of your parenthesis non-capturing and do some data cleaning

```
import re
data = []

tcp_dump = "17:18:38.877517 IP 192.168.0.15.43471 > 23.195.155.202.443: Flags [.], ack 1623866279, win 245, options [nop,nop,TS val 43001536 ecr 287517202], length 0"

regex = r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:length (\d+))'

# make the returned tuples into two lists, one containing the IPs and the 
# other containing the lengths. Finally, filter out empty strings.
data_ready,lengths = zip(*re.findall(regex, tcp_dump))
list_data = [ip for ip in list(data_ready) + list(lengths) if ip != '']
print(list_data)
data.append(list_data)

print(data)
```

output:

```
['192.168.0.15', '23.195.155.202', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it IP address matching (as `192.168.0.15.43471` is not valid IP address) but text parsing/processing. 
Optimized solution with `re.search()` function:

```
import re

tcp_dump = "17:18:38.877517 IP 192.168.0.15.43471 > 23.195.155.202.443: Flags [.], ack 1623866279, win 245, options [nop,nop,TS val 43001536 ecr 287517202], length 0"
result = re.search(r'((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(?:\.\d+) > ((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(?:\.\d+).*(\d+)$', tcp_dump)
result = list(result.groups())

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['192.168.0.15', '23.195.155.202', '0']
```

Comment: Valid IP, 192.168.0.15, 43471 is a mac address. this is from a TCP Dump file, this is what is attached to packets when sent accross networks and logged into files

Comment: @AhmedImran, it's just a dumping format, not standard, so not valid